# Use grep to parse a key from a json file and get the value

Tags: json, bash, awk, sed

Can someone suggest how I can get the value 45 after parsing an example json text as shown below :

```
....
"test": 12
"job": 45
"task": 11
.....
```

Please note that I am aware of tools like jq and others but this requires it to be installed.

I am hoping to get this executed using grep, awk or sed command.

Comment: Installing `jq` is not that hard: it's a single binary file (no external dependencies) that can be copied into any directory.

Comment: Why not use a specialized tool like `jq` for the job, `jq` is `sed` for`json`

Comment: Also that doesn't look like valid json to me :/

Comment: Is Python, PHP or Perl installed on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*' '/^[[:space:]]*"job"/{ print $2 }'
sed -n 's/^[[:space:]]*"job"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*//p'
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that a key in a json file starts at the begin of the line. While a simple task can indeed be done with grep/sed/awk, I would strongly recommend `jq`. It's not hard to install it - like [chepner mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878724/use-grep-to-parse-a-key-from-a-json-file-and-get-the-value#comment65119527_38878724)

Comment: The OP already stated he can't/won't install `jq` and asked for a solution using standard UNIX tools instead. I use plenty of machines where I don't have permission to install any tools, maybe that's the case for the OP too, idk. I also use lots of machines I have to jump on and do something with quickly so I tend to avoid solutions that use non-standard tools for that reason too. I'll add some optional white space at the front in case the OPs real input doesn't follow the format of the input he posted.

Comment: Sure, for a short interactive hack that might be good enough. But for a script or program not. If the OP can't use `jq`, he can use a scripting language like PHP, Python, Perl or whatever. Something that can process json is almost certainly installed.

Comment: If jq WAS installed then he'd probably have php, pyhon, perl, etc. but if it's not then there's no reason to think any of those others non-standard tools are and if the OP can't install jq then he almost certainly can't install any of the others.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -oP` (PCRE):

```
grep -oP '"job"\s*:\s*\K\d+' file

45
```

`\K` is used for reseting the previously matched data.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`, if you just want to print it:

```
awk -F ':[ \t]*' '/^.*"job"/ {print $2}' filename
```

Above command matches any line that has `"job"` at the beginning of a line, and then prints the `second` column of that line. awk option `-F` is used to set the column separator as `:` followed by any number of `spaces` or `tabs`.

If you want to store this value in bash variable `job_val`:

```
job_val=$(awk -F ':[ \t]*' '/^.*"job"/ {print $2}' filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use specialized tools like `jq` for the task :

Had your `file` looked like

```
[
{
"test": 12,
"job": 45,
"task": 11
}
]
```

below stuff would get you home

```
jq ".[].job" file
```

Had your `file` looked like

```
{
"stuff" :{
.
.
"test": 12,
"job": 45,
"task": 11
.
.
}
}
```

below

```
jq ".stuff.job" file
```

would get you home.